# Her car is black. vs The car of her is black

Tags: possessive-pronouns

Does the phrase ''The car of her is black'' sound as natural as ''Her car is black'' ?

Answer (score 2):

It does not sound normal at all. In the context you give, the only correct use of "her" is as a determiner:  "her car".  You can't use "of" for possession with "her" for this sense.

It is possible to use "of" with a noun phrase "The car of Jane". It is not the usual expression but may be of use when the noun phrase is long and complex "The car of the third woman in the queue with red hair", and there is an expression "A car of hers" to indicate possession that does not determine or identify the car, again - not common.

Answer (score 0):

You could also say "The color of her car is black", although even that sounds somewhat odd (mostly just very stilted). Not nearly as bad as "The car of her is black", that just sounds like someone who doesn't really understand the English language.